# Flutter::iOS Multiple Schemes Different Firebase Projects

Tags: ios, flutter, development-environment, production-environment

I am having multiple env scheme setup dev and prod and consequently I have two firebase projects for each env. I set up two schemes prod and dev on iOS and did follow instructions step by step as of the link https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/ However when I try to sign in using google single signin I get this error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(google_sign_in, Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes` What I am missing?

Error Log:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(google_sign_in, Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx-yyyyy, NSInvalidArgumentException)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349:48)
#3      MethodChannelGoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart:45:10)
#4      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:227:42)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:291:16)
#6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zon<…>
Lost connection to device.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think You need to get the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID
Found in the google-services.json or GoogleService-Info.plist and add it in XCode in URL Schemes
[image]
You can check this link for more details

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: For me even after putting the string there (was there before too) it shows the same problem. ):

Comment: Same problem with @JorgeVieira

Comment: did you run the project from xcode after putting it?